# SQL Server + delete multiple IDs

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to find out what is a good way to go about deleting a checkboxes of ids as seen below, for inserting, I am using SqlBulkCopy but I think there isn't a similar class for deleting. I can only think of deleting 1 by 1 now if the checkbox is checked but not sure if it's the best way to go about, the maximum count to the foreach row is about 15, also is it possible to include a transaction rollback for a 1 by 1 delete? Thanks.

```
 protected void DeleteMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserBLL userBll = new UserBLL();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in uigvUserInbox.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

                if (chkSelected.Checked)
                {
                    try
                    {
                      //  DataKey currentDataKey = uigvUserInbox.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex];
                      //  userBll.DeleteMessage(currentDataKey.Value.ToString()); // SQL delete 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // clsLogging logError = new clsLogging();
                        // logError.WriteLog(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the appropriate method to the `UserBLL` class which executes a delete on the SQL side with a `where yourMappedIDColumn in (here is the comma separated list of dataKeys)`

```
class UserBLL
{
    internal void DeleteMessages(List<DataKey> dataKeysToDelete)
    {
        //delete from tableName where Id in dataKeysToDelete
    }
}
```

Retrieve all data keys in a variable and pass it to the metod above.

```
protected void DeleteMsg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserBLL userBll = new UserBLL();

    List<DataKey> dataKeysToDelete = new List<DataKey>();

    foreach (GridViewRow row in uigvUserInbox.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");

        if (chkSelected.Checked)
        {

            dataKeysToDelete.Add(uigvUserInbox.DataKeys[row.DataItemIndex]);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        userBll.DeleteMessages(dataKeysToDelete);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // clsLogging logError = new clsLogging();
        // logError.WriteLog(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an In clause

Delete from table where id in (id1, id2, id3)

This will only take one query.